# Flowtype: array of possible strings cannot be empty?

Tags: flowtype

if I create this Flow type:

```
export type List = [
    'some' |
    'strings' |
    'allowed' |
    'to' |
    'use'
];
```

I am not allowed to:
`const myList: List = [];`

this is the error:
`empty array literal:
This type is incompatible with a tuple type that expects a 1st element of non-optional type string enum`

The only thing I can come up with is adding `typeof undefined` to the possible values list. But there must be a simpeler way to allow it to be empty?

Comment: This is the tuple syntax: https://flowtype.org/docs/arrays.html#tuples . What you've written is the type of a single-element array that contains one of those strings. gcanti has explained how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You defined a tuple of one element, you may want

```
type Element = 
  'some' |
  'strings' |
  'allowed' |
  'to' |
  'use';

export type List = Element[];
// or export type List = Array<Element>;

const myList: List = []
```